# Show how long has passed since last click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save the time the user clicks on the page. So I can later return how long ago he clicked with a function.

I think it should basically work like this:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var lastClick = currentTime.getTime();
$("body").click(function () {
var lastClick = currentTime.getTime();
    });

function howlong() {
console.log('last click was: ' + currentTime.getTime() - lastClick + 'ms ago');
}
```

However I Cannot make it work. howlong keeps returning 0. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to remove the `var` from within the handler, otherwise you're declaring `lastClick` *again* in the local scope, and you're never actually setting the variable you think you are.
2. A `Date` instance doesn't *update*. It's value will *always* be the time it was constructed at; you'll have to do a new `new Date()` each time you want a new *now*.

With both of these taken into consideration, the following should work;

```
var lastClick;
$("body").click(function () {
    lastClick = (new Date()).getTime();
});

function howlong() {
    console.log('last click was: ' + ((new Date()).getTime() - lastClick) + 'ms ago');
}
```

Note the potentially *WTF* extra `()` around the `new Date()`. This ensures that a new Date is constructed, and `getTime()` being called on that, rather than `Date().getTime()` being called, and then `new` being called on that (which is wrong!).

You also have to wrap the math `-` in brackets inside `howlong()`, to do the math before the string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Your modified code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSkyd/1/)

```
var  lastClick ;

$(document).click(function () {
      lastClick = Date.now();
        setTimeout(howlong, 100);//call howlong after 100 ms (this line for testing only). you can call howlong from anywhere in doc to get difference.
    });

function howlong() {
             console.log('last click was: ' +( Date.now() - lastClick ) + 'ms ago');
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

lastClick is only valid within the scope of the jQuery function. You need to declare it outside that function

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var lastClick;
$("body").click(function () {
lastClick = currentTime.getTime();
    });

function howlong() {
console.log('last click was: ' + currentTime.getTime() - lastClick + 'ms ago');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global var:

```
    var lastEvent;

    $('selector').bind('event', function() {
            lastEvent = new Date().getTime();  //new Date() is important here
    });
```

Comment: just one note, if you change the word 'selector' and 'event' for something appropriate to this example your question will be much better, you need a little more effort.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
var lastClick = "";
var presentClick = "";
document.onclick=function(e){
 var evt=window.event || e 

 lastClick = currentTime;
 presentClick = new Date().getTime();

 idleTime = parseInt(presentClick) - parseInt(lastClick);
 alert("Last Click = "+lastClick+"\n\nPresent Click = "+presentClick+"\n\nIdle Time = "+idleTime+" ms.");

 currentTime = presentClick;

}
</script>
```